# Did Octavian Augustus have a famous horse?

Tags: ancient-rome

Did Octavian [Augustus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus) (the founder of the Roman empire) have a famous horse like Bucephalus, and if so, do we know that horse's name?

Comment: If he were famous, you would have already heard of him.

Comment: @SPavel - [This link](https://www.thecollector.com/famous-horses-ancient-world/) does actually make the claim that Augustus had a "famous horse" (suspiciously similar phrasing to this question). However, I haven't run down the sourcing, which these days means there's the distinct possibility its utter BS made up by an AI to finish out a question prompt.

Comment: @T.E.D. It seems that Pliny does indeed [mention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanicus#cite_note-88) this horse - in a throw-away note that Germanicus wrote a poem about it: ["The deified  Augustus also made a funeral mound for a horse, which is the subject of a poem by Germanicus Caesar."](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/L/Roman/Texts/Pliny_the_Elder/8*.html#64). Since nothing else is known about it (we do not even have this poem), I cannot say it counts as famous.

Comment: @SPavel - Well, the dude who wrote that article clearly disagrees. :-) (assuming it was a human). Either way, seems like you've got enough information in that comment to make a quick answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

We do know that Octavian (Emperor Augustus) was a fan of horses: he [built the Circus Maximus](https://www.italymagazine.com/featured-story/augustus-stables-rome-be-reburied-lack-funds) and is noted among other equestrians (the practice, not the [social order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equites)) by Pliny the Elder in the entry about horses of his [Natural History](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/L/Roman/Texts/Pliny_the_Elder/8%2A.html).

Unfortunately, the note is extremely brief:

> fecit et Divus Augustus equo tumulum, de quo Germanici Caesaris carmen est.

> [The deified  Augustus also made a funeral mound for a horse, which is the subject of a poem by Germanicus Caesar.](https://www.attalus.org/translate/pliny_hn8b.html)

Sadly, the poem does not survive to this day, and we know nothing else about the horse (though presumably it belonged to Octavian and was a favorite).

Since many horse names from Ancient Rome are known to this day (horses could be [as famous as their charioteers](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/%7Egrout/encyclopaedia_romana/circusmaximus/leontius.html) and many of their names survive in mosaics or preserved texts) we can conclude that Octavian's horse was not even very well known *compared to contemporary Roman horses*, never mind being famous enough for his name to echo through the centuries like Bucephalus.

Comment: I ribbed a bit, but the added content here makes a pretty good case for the "no". Perhaps doesn't mean it wasn't famous *at the time*, but I'll give it to you. Thanks for the answer!